# how to Remove html table element properly in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, ngfor, ngmodel

I try to develop dynamic table with Add/Remove element button.
Each row have 2 cells - 1 is selected cell (which could be disabled/enabled) and input field (maybe important to make that clear).
I do that with Array (which store my object), `ngModel` and indexed `ngFor` to iterate over it.

Have problem when I try to delete element, then for some reason after I'm trying to add element to the table not all the data binding (not in the right state nor shown in the input field) properly, even though all the data is stored well.

I use to think that there is a problem with the `ngFor` index, maybe when I update the array the `ngFor` not started from 0, so my `ngModel` and my attributes refer to the last element (which is empty new object).
Thanks for helps, the relevant code attached.

```js
addIncludeRule() {
    this.campaign.includeRules.push({
        "data": "",
        "includeData": "",
        "excludeData": "",
        "type": ""
    });
}
//==========================================================================
public removeIncludeRule(i: number) {
    this.campaign.includeRules.splice(i, 1);
}
```

```html
<tbody class="esf-table__body">
  <tr class="esf-table__row" *ngFor="let irule of campaign.includeRules; index as i">
    <td class="esf-table__cell">
      <select [(ngModel)]="irule.type" name=iruleType{{i}} (change)="disabledOptionFlags(irule.type,0)" class="esf-form-item__field esf-select__field" [disabled]="irule.type[i]">
        <option *ngFor="let ioption of options" value={{ioption.value}}       [disabled]=ioption.incDisabled>{{(irule.data) ? irule.type : ioption.value}}</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="esf-table__cell">
      <input [(ngModel)]="irule.data" name=iruleValue{{i}} class="esf-form-item__field"                           type="text" value={{irule.data}} />
    </td>
    <td class="esf-table__cell esf-table__cell--shrink">
        <span class="esf-table__cell-inner">
          <div *ngIf="incRulesSize != i+1; else addIncButton">
          <button class="esf-button esf-button--simple" mat-button               (click)="removeIncludeRule(i)"> 
            <svg class="esf-icon esf-button__icon" width="16" height="16">
              <use xlink:href="#esf-icon-trash-16"></use>
            </svg>
            <span class="esf-button__icon-text"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <ng-template #addIncButton>
            <div class="esf-submit-row__item">
                <button class="esf-button esf-button--standard esf-button--filled" (click)="addIncludeRule()" [disabled]="incRulesLimit">Add</button>
              </div>
        </ng-template>
        </span>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `trackBy` to let angular know to track the index, so for your iteration, just add:

```
*ngFor="let irule of campaign.includeRules; index as i; trackBy: myTrackByFn"
```

and in component:

```
myTrackByFn(index) {
  return index;
}
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear! If it solved your issue, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick below this answer, which marks the question as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't using types?

Why you have `[disabled]="irule.type[i]` but type is string and in your initialization you have empty value, so should return `OutOfRangeException` in JavaScript

Why you don't remove `ngModel` from `ngForm`?
e.g.:

```
@ViewChild(NgForm) form : NgForm;
removeExample(index: number){
   let currentControlName: string = `iruleValue${i}`
   let control:NgModel = this.form.controls[currentControlName];
   control && this.form.removeControl(control)
   this.campaign.includeRules.splice(i, 1)
   this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
}
```